# Read a web page with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read the content of a web page with perl on Windows 10. The code does not work for the following site:

https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/

Here is the code I am using:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
my $url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/';
my $html = get $url;
print $html;
```

Any idea why I cannot read that page?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot read"? What error are you getting?

Comment: Look at the response headers to see what errors the server might be returning. From [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple): *The get() function will fetch the document identified by the given URL and return it. It returns undef if it fails. The $url argument can be either a string or a reference to a URI object.

You will not be able to examine the response code or response headers (like Content-Type) when you are accessing the web using this function. If you need that information you should use the full OO interface (see LWP::UserAgent).*

Comment: No errors. Just dont get the HTML on my screen. With other links I get the entire HTML of the web page.

Comment: Speculation: The people running the site want you to look at their ads and not just scrape data with bots and so have banned your UA.

Comment: Ok. I got you. So this mean that even with Python using BeatifulSoup I will not be able to read the content.

Comment: I tried with see LWP::UserAgent) - but failed also to get the data

Comment: It means you need to read up on how this kind of stuff works. You might well find a tool that sends a User Agent header out of the box which they haven't listed as a scraper yet. Or you can learn how to change that header to send something else. You should look at the website's terms of service to learn whether you are allowed to scrape the data at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) is pretty basic and doesn't let you do anything clever like actually looking at the details of the response. So let's change to [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and see what the response is.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

print $resp->status_line;
```

This prints:

> 403 Forbidden

So I think that Quentin's comment is correct and that the site's owners are blocking people who use technology like LWP.

So let's change the useragent string to look like Internet Explorer.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

my $url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent($agent);

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

print $resp->status_line;
```

Now I get:

> 200 OK

So we should be ok to get the content.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

my $url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent($agent);

my $resp = $ua->get($url);

if ($resp->is_success) {
  print $resp->content;
} else {
  print $resp->status_line;
}
```

And that seems to work fine.

**Note:** Of course, changing the useragent string like this is rather dishonest. Presumably, the site's owners have a good reason for wanting to dissuade people from accessing their site in this way. So don't annoy them by trying to get around their restrictions. Read the site'sterms of service to see what they want to to do. Perhaps they have an API available that will give you the data you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As Dave Cross wrote, the problem is related to the user agent. It is possible to use the LWP::Simple module in this way:

```
use LWP::Simple qw/$ua get/;

$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
my $url = 'https://www.dividendinvestor.com/dividend-quote/intc/';
my $html = get $url;
print $html;
```

As the documentation points, the user agent created by this module (LWP::Simple) will identify itself as "LWP::Simple/#.##". So we can change it before the "GET" request.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miguel. I appreciate your help